# How to keep focus on an input in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I have multiple .php-pages for specific manipulations of a SQL-table. These are accessible through another page with an iFrame and their various links.

So page1 looks like this:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="cat1">
            <a href="#"  onClick="page.location.href = 'page2.php' ; document.getElementById('page').style.height='880px';">Read</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<iframe id="page" name="page" width="100%" style="background-color:#FFFFFF" frameborder="0"  marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

page2 looks like this:

First a script in the head:

```
<script>
function submitter(){
    document.getElementById('form1').submit();
    document.getElementById('scan').focus();
}
</script>
```

and the body:

```
<form  action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="Formular" id="form1">
<input type="text" name="scan" id="scan" style="border-radius:8px; border-color:#000000;" autofocus autocomplete="off" onChange="submitter()">
```

page2 is operating by reading a barcode, writing it in the text input and submitting for an SQL-query. I wanna keep the focus on the text input cause I wanna save a click on approx. 100 reads a day. My script works, when I open page2 on its own but not in the iFrame.

Any clue on how I can keep the cursor in my input?

EDIT

So far after looking into addEventListener I added the following script to page1:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('page');
iframe.contentWindow.body.addEventListener('submit', function(evt){
evt.preventDefault();
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
innerDoc.getElementByID('scan').focus();
});
```

This doesn't work though. It might just be a misunderstanding on my end but I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Do you have control over both the parent document and the iFrame's source code? 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage is a good way to interact between iframe and parent document via javascript, you could write a function that posts a message to the child iframe telling it to execute various functions, including a "focus input" function etc

Comment: @Scuzzy first of all thanks for the reply. If I understand correctly, I could add an EventListener to page1, that listens for the submit to then send a postMessage with a GetElementById().focus() to page2, correct?

Comment: That is correct, its an event driven communication API. But would send a object structure commanding the other page to run various tasks.

Answer (score 0):

on second page you can add:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    // assuming you're having different HTML file for each page.
    // when this page is loaded, it will focus elemen with id scan
    document.getElementById('scan').focus();
});
```